# How to align a single header to the right?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, minipage

This is my situation

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
\section{Section 1}
Content 1
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}

\section{Section 2}
\footnotesize \raggedleft
Content 2
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

I want the header of section 2 to be aligned right but it seems harder than I expected. Using `\section{\raggedleft Section 2}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you really desire multiple columns (as per your `minipage`s) or was that merely an attempt to right-align the header for section 2?

Comment: I do want them and they are almost perfect for what I need. I just need that damn header to align on the right and I'm done.

Comment: By "damn header", do you mean "2 Section 2" or merely "Section 2", with the leading 2 remaining where it is based on the `minipage` width?

Comment: `\section{\hfill Section 2}`

Comment: \raggedleft befor \section{...} do what you need

Comment: \raggedleft ignored section. I've tried it already. 

@StevenB.Segletes is right though. It worked.

Comment: No \raggedleft do the job and yes StevenB.Segletes is right